# How can i convert Javascript regular expression to C++11 regular expression

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to convert javascript regular expression into C++11 regex.

javaScript regular expression: **"/google-analytics.([a-z.]+)/i"**

Match URL is : http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

So what should be the perfect C++11 regular expression for this URL match????

Comment: JavaScript is the common name for ECMAScript. And the default regex variant in C++ is ECMAScript. So you should not need to do anything with the actual regex itself (`google-analytics.([a-z.]+)`).

Answer (score 2):

The JS

```
let re = /google-analytics.([a-z.]+)/i
```

corresponds to

```
std::regex re("google-analytics.([a-z.]+)", std::regex_constants::icase);
```

By default C++ uses the same syntax as JS for regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you caleth for your replay.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
 
int main()
{
 std::string input;
  std::regex reg("google-analytics.([a-z.]+)", std::regex_constants::icase);;
  //As long as the input is correct ask for another number
  while(true)
  {
   std::cout<<"Give me an Input!"<<std::endl;
   std::cin>>input;
   if(!std::cin) break;
   //Exit when the user inputs q
   if(input=="q")
    break;
   if(regex_match(input,reg))
    std::cout<<"Match Success"<<std::endl;
   else
   {
    std::cout<<"Invalid input"<<std::endl;
   }
  }

}

Comment: This is my code. My input is "http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js". So i want expression match result must be "Match Success".

Comment: @SantoshSalunke If that is your input then the regex string should be `google-analytics.([a-z./]+)`

Comment: use `std::regex_search`, not `std::regex_match`. `regex_match` is for full matches, whereas `regex_search` will match part of `input`